# How to send kill signal to java process running on server?

Tags: java

I have some Java code running on server in infinite loop. Currently I am using `"kill -9 process_id"` to stop process. But kill command forcefully stop Java process without cleaning resource.

I want to implement signal handler in Java just like C++ so that I can clean all resource and gracefully stop Java process.

Can anyone please suggest me the right way to do this?

Comment: jmx is for that kind of job.

Comment: I used "addShutdownHook" and "kill -15 process_id" to kill java process. And it's working. Is there any better way to do this?